# How to refresh the page on which iFrame is loaded after getting response

Tags: javascript, c#, iframe, extjs

I have a C# page called default.aspx, from where I open the iFrame. once I get the response I set the value in my session. But due to lack of page refresh I unable to get a value shown on the page and hide iframe.

I used many posssible Js function:

window.parent.location = document.referrer
location.top.reload

I was expecting to refresh my page once I get the response from Iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.postMessage` to communicate with the parent of `iframe`.

In your iframe:

```
window.parent.postMessage("loaded");
```

Inside your parent `aspx`:

```
window.addEventListener("loaded", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
   // do reload
   window.location.reload();
}
```

You can read more about this API here in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

TL;DR:

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin
>   communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a
>   pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded
>   within it.
>
> Normally, scripts on different pages are allowed to access each other
>   if and only if the pages they originate from share the same protocol,
>   port number, and host (also known as the "same-origin policy").
>   window.postMessage() provides a controlled mechanism to securely
>   circumvent this restriction (if used properly).
>
> Broadly, one window may obtain a reference to another (e.g., via
>   targetWindow = window.opener), and then dispatch a MessageEvent on it
>   with targetWindow.postMessage(). The receiving window is then free to
>   handle this event as needed. The arguments passed to
>   window.postMessage() (i.e., the “message”) are exposed to the
>   receiving window through the event object.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick thought... can't you use ajax to fetch the value and refresh only the particular div tag..

if you really wanna refresh the page.. you can try something like document.location.reload(true)